# How to push one object in multidimensional array using java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to push one object in multidimensional array. I know **javascript**..I have javascript examples..But i don't know how to use that method in **java**

Javascript Examples :

```js
var obj = [{
 "plicenceKey": "BI-NBPM39",
 "LicenceList": [{
  "billDurationName": "Month(s)",
  "planName": "jhkhjg",
  "licenceCreatedDate": "2018fdg01-02 12:14:56",
  "vehicleId": "90",
  "trailperday": "0",
  
 },{
  "billDurationName": "ffdhfg(s)",
  "planName": "jhkhjg",
  "licenceCreatedDate": "fdghdfg-01-12:14:56",
  "vehicleId": "78",
  "trailperday": "0",
  
 },{
  "billDurationName": "dfhfgh(s)",
  "planName": "jhkhjg",
  "licenceCreatedDate": "dfghfg-01-02 12::56",
  "vehicleId": "67",
  "trailperday": "0",
  
 }]
}]

var b = {
  "billDurationName": "test",
  "planName": "ghgfd",
  "licenceCreatedDate": "ghf-01-02 12::56",
  "vehicleId": "34",
  "trailperday": "0",
  
 };

obj[0].LicenceList.push(b)
```

How to wrote in java? Please give some example in java ..

Comment: You cannot add elements to an array in Java. But you can use a list instead.

Comment: You should be using a JSON library here.

Comment: You've already added `ArrayList` as a tag, so you know the collection to use.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Map as `obj` and  `b`
here is Example

```
    Map obj=new HashMap();
    Map b=new HashMap();
    obj.put("billDurationName","Month(s)");
    obj.put("planName","jhkhjg");
    b.put("LicenceList", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 License will be a separate object called License with the respective fields. Then the collection (called ListLicense in your case), will be java List (ArrayList). And then you can do:

`myList.add(newLicense);`

where `newLicense` will be your new License object.

But yes, if it is mapped by licenseKey, then you need a Map, not a List

Answer (score 0):

But have push the object to particular index of object..

For example

```js
var obj = [  
   {  
      "plicenceKey":"key1",
      "LicenceList":[  
         {  
            "billDurationName":"Month(s)",
            "planName":"jhkhjg",
            "licenceCreatedDate":"2018fdg01-02 12:14:56",
            "vehicleId":"90",
            "trailperday":"0"
         },
         {  
            "billDurationName":"ffdhfg(s)",
            "planName":"jhkhjg",
            "licenceCreatedDate":"fdghdfg-01-12:14:56",
            "vehicleId":"78",
            "trailperday":"0"
         },
         {  
            "billDurationName":"dfhfgh(s)",
            "planName":"jhkhjg",
            "licenceCreatedDate":"dfghfg-01-02 12::56",
            "vehicleId":"67",
            "trailperday":"0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "plicenceKey":"key2",
      "LicenceList":[  
         {  
            "billDurationName":"Month(s)",
            "planName":"jhkhjg",
            "licenceCreatedDate":"2018fdg01-02 12:14:56",
            "vehicleId":"90",
            "trailperday":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
];

var b = {
  "billDurationName": "test",
  "planName": "ghgfd",
  "licenceCreatedDate": "ghf-01-02 12::56",
  "vehicleId": "34",
  "trailperday": "0",
  
 };

obj[1].LicenceList.push(b)
```

:
I have to add the **object b** to the array that contains **plicenceKey:key2** of the **LicenceList**..

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize multidimensional json objects with Gson library

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String[][] multiIntArray
 = new String[][]{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}};

// serialization
gson.toJson(multiIntArray);   

// deserialization
String[][] intArray2
= gson.fromJson("[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]]", String[][].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this kind of structure in Java is to use one of the various third-party JSON libraries.

However, if you want a direct answer and a direct Java equivalent of your JavaScript code...

`obj` is initialized as a `List<Map<String,Object>>`.

It contains a single element which is a `Map` with two entries. The first entry has a `String` key which maps to a `String` value. The second entry has a `String` key which maps to a `List` of `Map`s, each map having string keys and values (so it's a `List<Map<String,String>>`).

Here's the direct Java equivalent to your code:

```
List<Map<String,Object>> obj =
    new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new HashMap<>(Map.of(
            "plicenceKey", "BI-NBPM39",
            "LicenceList", new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                Map.of(
                    "billDurationName": "Month(s)",
                    "planName": "jhkhjg",
                    "licenceCreatedDate": "2018fdg01-02 12:14:56",
                    "vehicleId": "90",
                    "trailperday": "0"),
                Map.of(...),
                ...))))));

Map<String,String> b = Map.of(
    "billDurationName": "test",
    "planName": "ghgfd",
    "licenceCreatedDate": "ghf-01-02 12::56",
    "vehicleId": "34",
    "trailperday": "0");

obj.get(0).get("LicenceList").add(b);
```

By the way, I've used the new Java 9 collection literals for convenience. If you don't have Java 9, you can procedurally add each element to the collection.